# Go to next frame in external flash Action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have two buttons:

- First button load swf.
- Second button go to next frame in this swf.

Code for second button not working.

This is my code:

[image]

Comment: Please add the code in your question as **text**, do not link image for code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ProLoader` class has `content` property.

> content : DisplayObject
>
> Contains the root display object
>   of the SWF file or image (JPG, PNG, or GIF) file that was loaded by
>   using the load() or loadBytes() methods.

So, your code should looks like this:

```
(fl_ProLoader.content as MovieClip).nextFrame();
```

Comment: @m_way2allah `another_mc.fl_ProLoader`